# jQuery if statment on click event not working in Chrome but working in firefox browser

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have used this code for hiding and showing element, but my JQuery code not working in chrome in else statement but it works correctly in Firefox browser.

`Code`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".item-title").on("click",function () {
      $(this).next('div').children().toggle();
      $(this).children().children('.fa-plus-square').hide()
      $(this).children().children('.fa-minus-square').show()
      if ($(this).next('div').children().is(':hidden')){
          $(this).addClass('bb')
      }
      else {
          $(this).removeClass('bb')
      }
  })
```

don't Remove class in if statement

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".item-title").on("click",function () {
        var currentClickedObject = $(this);
      currentClickedObject.next('div').children().toggle();
      currentClickedObject.children().children('.fa-plus-square').hide();
      currentClickedObject.children().children('.fa-minus-square').show();
      if (currentClickedObject.next('div').children().is(':hidden')){
          currentClickedObject.toggleClass('bb');
      }
      else {
          currentClickedObject.toggleClass('bb');
      }
  });
  });
```

Comment: updated the code. It's better to use toggle class. Also you missed to close the parenthesis for document.ready function.

Comment: Why do you think `toggleClass`is better? The idea of "toggle" is to alternate the state of something. If you didn't have an "if statement" in your code, "toggle" would be a good solution. Having `toggleClass` inside the "else" condition is actually creating a broken behaviour. Please update your answer :)

Comment: Hi Bruno, please see line no 4 of code and compare it with if statement. For this particular problem statement toggleclass would work and would not break.